# Transform async into sync

Tags: c++, asynchronous, synchronization

I know that this might be a generic question, but I am trying to wrap my head around this and I don't know how to solve it.

We have a project where the previous sdk had sync calls to it and now we are trying to replace that sdk, with a new one that works asynchronously.

We also had a wrapper that we used as a middle ground between our application and the sdk. We have to keep from the perspective of the applications "the sync aproach", where they block and wait response/data.

The new async SDK has a main callback thread where we get notified for each request that we did based on the request ID.

So now I am trying to figure out a good way of making this async calls to the sdk, and afterwards block somehow until a certain time expired/the result of the command is received and return the results received on the callback thread back to where the request was made, in order to pass the information to the applications ?
Also because the sdks are different, sometimes to get the same data we need to call multiple sdk apis.

I would be grateful if you have some ideas or some documentation on this specific case on how to solve the issue.

Thank you very much in advance.

Lets say we have the following code:

```
bool DeviceService::getDeviceInformation (DeviceInfo& devInfo) const
{
    if(CM2MWSession::getInstance().isInit())
    {
         NOTIFICATION_REQUEST_DATA rqst;
         rqst.sender_id = CM2MWSession::getInstance().getClientId();

            get_serial_number(&rqst,NULL))
            get_sim_serial_number(&rqst,NULL))
    }
}
```

The  *get_serial_number* and *get_sim_serial_number* are async calls to the sdk.

The *getDeviceInformation* is the method called from the aplication side.

The main callback looks something like this:

```
mainCallback(REQUEST_DATA *rqst_data, uint32 size, void *data)
```

Here  we receive an *rqst_data->feat_id)* for each request type.
From here we have to somehow return to the *getDeviceInfo* with the data returned by this callback.

Comment: You should paste some of the code you are working with converting.

Comment: Wait on a `condition_variable` after the asynchronous calls; have the callback notify that variable.